# Unable to connect to asynchronous server using async/await

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to make a very simple client-server application with asynchronous server using async/await. I have 2 projects in a solution:

Server is a console application. Server code:

```
class Program
{
    static async void Run()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server is running...");
        Console.WriteLine("Server is listening on port 5000...");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
            Socket s = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
            //Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();

            Console.WriteLine("Socket accepted.");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }
}
```

Client is a windows forms application. Client code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000));
    }
}
```

When I run both projects and click the button, I get System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it).

Synchronous server works fine:

```
//Socket s = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
```

I have been searching for two days and I haven't found anything that could help. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Your server will probably exit immediately. Try making the method signature `static async Task Run()` and then wait for its result in the `main` method like this: `Run().Wait();`

Comment: @YacoubMassad This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console application, when you run this the application will actually close immediately. You need to invoke the `.Wait()` on the `Run` method to prevent this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Run().Wait();
}
```

Additionally, your `Run` method should be defined like this (`Task` returning):

```
static async Task Run()
{
    // Omitted for brevity...
}
```

Otherwise, it is fire-and-forget.